# What is the Watson card's ability?

Tags: watson-and-holmes

On page 12 of the [Rulebook](https://images-cdn.asmodee.us/filer_public/b6/27/b627fd15-44ae-4c65-b286-6dc141515031/wah_rulebook.pdf), it says

> At the start of the Investigation Phase of this round, the holder of this card may choose the Location card of another player which is read out loud

Does this mean the player can direct someone to read his card out loud to the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever I've played it, the player who chose that location must read it out loud to the table.

Group policies differ as to how slowly and audibly the choosing player should be required to read it, though there is a convention that listeners may not ask for bits to be repeated.